# What is the type of http.Get, to use as a parameter in a function?

Tags: go, types

I would like to write a small helper function to centralize my HTTP calls. Coming from Python I still struggle with the usage of pointers in Go.

The helper function essentially takes a `struct` with the call information (URL, method and an optional request body) and will return the response body as `[]byte` (for now it is `nil`):

```
package main

import "net/http"

type httpParameters struct {
    Url string
    Method func(client http.Client, string2 string) (*http.Response, error)
    Body []byte
}

func callHTTP(param httpParameters) (resp []byte, err error) {
    return nil, nil
}
```

The attached test is

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "testing"
)

func TestCallHTTP(t *testing.T) {
    params := httpParameters{
        Url:    "https://postman-echo.com/get",
        Method: http.Client.Get,
    }
    resp, err := callHTTP(params)
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("call to %v was not successful: %v", params.Url, err)
    }
    if resp != nil {
        t.Errorf("GET call to %v returned something: %v, should be nil", params.Url, resp)
    }
}
```

When trying to run that I get

```
.\main_test.go:11:22: invalid method expression http.Client.Get (needs pointer receiver: (*http.Client).Get)
```

Note: `Method func(client http.Client, string2 string) (*http.Response, error)` in the type declaration was a trial and error approach - I ended up putting what is in the `Get` definition. I am not sure this is the way such functions should be referred to

How should I address the `Get` method to be able to pass it in the call?

Comment: Populate an `http.Request` structure, pass it to http.Client.Do method. The example right there in the docs (3rd example box from the top): https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/

Comment: Not really clear what the intention is with `Method`.  `http.Client.Get` is a method with a receiver, `httpParameters.Method` on the other hand is a function. They don't match.

Comment: @super: I wanted to say "the method that should be used is "GET"" - this was to avoid writing a helper for GET, another one for POST etc. oakad's comment points to the proper solution I think (way more elegant at least)

Comment: "GET" is a string, so the Method field should just have type `string`. Note that http.Client.Get is just a convience wrapper around http.Client.Do. Whenever you have to be flexible, use Do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Get`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Get) is declared with a pointer receiver, i.e. `*http.Client` and *not* with a value receiver, i.e. *not* `http.Client`.

The error:

```
invalid method expression http.Client.Get (needs pointer receiver: (*http.Client).Get)
```

says just that. And, it even provides the proper form of the [method expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions), i.e. `(*http.Client).Get`.

This also means that your function's signature must change accordingly, i.e. change `client http.Client` to `client *http.Client`.

```golang
type httpParameters struct {
    Url string
    Method func(*http.Client, string) (*http.Response, error)
    Body []byte
}
```

```golang
func TestCallHTTP(t *testing.T) {
    params := httpParameters{
        Url:    "https://postman-echo.com/get",
        Method: (*http.Client).Get,
    }
    // ...
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/83qgE4QeHx5

Answer (score 2):

`http.NewRequest(method, url, body)` will help to achieve the same.

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://example.com", nil)
// ...
req.Header.Add("If-None-Match", `W/"wyzzy"`)
resp, err := client.Do(req)
// ...
```